# Tabular Editor - Set "Shared Expression" value from Tabular Editor CLI (with Azure Devops)

Tags: azure, powerbi, tabular

I need to change the value of a parameter in a TOM. I am using Azure Devops with steps that include Tabular Editor CLI. I have written a one-line script that should be able to change the value of a Shared Expression. (Maybe a shared expression is read only?)

The script that will be executed

```
Model.Expressions["CustomerNameParameter"].Expression = "\"some value\" meta [IsParameterQuery=true, Type=\"Text\", IsParameterQueryRequired=true]";
```

I returns an error whenever Azure Devops tries to run it:
[image]

It cannot find the CustomerNameParameter in the model.

My build looks like this:

```
Starting: Build Mode.bim from SourceDirectory
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.201.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents: shell
TabularEditor.exe "D:\a\1\s" -B "D:\a\1\a\Model.bim"
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\ba31b528-d9a3-42cc-9099-d80d46d1ffe6.cmd""

Tabular Editor 2.12.4 (build 2.12.7563.29301)
--------------------------------
Dependency tree built in 113 ms
Loading model...
Building Model.bim file...
Finishing: Build Mode.bim from SourceDirectory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script looks good. Have you tried executing it within the Tabular Editor UI?

[image]

Perhaps the parameter is named differently in your model. You  can use the following script in the CLI to output the list of parameters:

```cs
foreach(var expr in Model.Expressions) Info(expr.Name);
```

The result when executed in the CLI on the model shown in the screenshot above:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I did to fix this is create a separate script (SharedExpressions.csx) and (manually) created this line for each expression:

`Model.Expressions["Start Date - Sales"].Expression = "#datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) meta [IsParameterQuery=true, Type=\"DateTime\", IsParameterQueryRequired=true]";`

In this case my Expressions are datetime, but you can change it to anything you like. Just be very aware with the quote placement.

Then in my pipeline I use the following script to execute the changes:

```
start /wait TabularEditor.exe "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Tabular Model/model/model.bim" -S "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Tabular Model/scripts/SharedExpressions.csx" -D -V
```

Answer (score 0):

My tabular model uses a shared expression (parameter) to set the connection string.  The following solution worked for me.  I updated the command line script in the release pipeline as follows:

```
echo var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLDWConnectionString"); >> SetConnectionStringFromEnv.cs  
echo Model.Expressions["ServerName"].Expression = "\"" + connectionString +"\"" + " meta [IsParameterQuery=true, Type=\"Text\", IsParameterQueryRequired=true]"; >> SetConnectionStringFromEnv.cs    

TabularEditor.exe "_$(Build.DefinitionName)\drop\Model.bim" -S  SetConnectionStringFromEnv.cs -D "%ASConnectionString%" "$(ASDatabaseName)"  -O -C -P -R -M -W -E -V
```